# Node js Date() is not showing system date and time in Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, time

When I type `date` in terminal it is showing the original date time. but when I use `new Date()` in node it is showing 6 hours back.

Note: the timezone of the machine was different at first. but I changed it using

`sudo timedatectl set-timezone` this command.

How can I make bothe time syncronized?

Comment: check your system default date and time first

Comment: @GauravMavani
default time is different than nodejs time
this is system default time: Sun Oct  2 12:03:11 +06 2022
this is node ja new Date() output: 2022-10-02T06:03:27.256Z

Comment: `2022-10-02T06:03:27.256Z` is exactly the same as `Sun Oct 2 12:03:11 +06 2022` - the former is UTC (GMT+0), the latter is whatever timezone you are in (Bangladesh Standard Time GMT+6 at a guess)  - try `new Date().toString()` - the

Answer (score -1):

You could try manually setting up the time. As always, I would encourage you to research the following commands prior to implementing to ensure trustworthiness. You can also utilize the man pages with # man command

```
$ ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Country/Region /etc/localtime
$ vi /etc/locale.gen
```

Uncomment yourlocaltime
Uncomment yourlocaltime2

```
$ locale-gen
$ echo LANG=yourlocaltime > /etc/locale.conf
$ export yourlocaltime
```

Follow up for safe measure with your time sync

```
$ timedatectl set-ntp true
```

An example for setting time for American/CDT would be the following process.

```
$ ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime
$ vi /etc/locale.gen
```

Uncomment en_US.UTF-8
Uncomment en_US ISO-8859-1

```
$ locale-gen

$ echo LANG=en_US.UTF-8 > /etc/locale.conf

$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

$ timedatectl set-ntp true
```